# How to create and edit a text file from the bash shell

Tags: command-line, editors

I am logged into a linux server via ssh. From the bash shell, is there any standard way of bringing up some kind of text editing environment so I can create and edit a text file? I am aware that there exist apps like emacs and vi, but I don't know if they are appropriate for basic text file editing or if I should use something simpler, or if not, which one to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's well-known fact, that vi has only two modes: it beeps and spoils text (:

So, if you're newbie and know nothing about vi and emacs, the best choice for you will be something simple like `nano`. It has hint in footer and it's easy to edit and save your edits.

But in case you want to be a good administrator, you should learn vi or emacs, because there're great and powerful editor's that can save a lot of time during text writing/editing.

ps. A little vi hint: To exit from vi just type `:q` .

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed, thanks! I'm not looking to be a great administrator right now, though I'm certainly looking to pick up more and more over time to let go of my dependence on Windows.

Comment: Awesome, Its very easy to use.